# Android - Download all files from a folder on server

Tags: android

Hope I am able to explain this correctly... 
I am able to connect to my web server and download a single file.What I am now attempting to do is connect to my server and download all the flies from a particular folder.In this case i want to download images.
This is the code i use to download a single file...

```
URL url  = new URL("http://127.0.0.1/Folder/file.csv");
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            File testDirectory = 
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Folder");
            if(!testDirectory.exists()){
                testDirectory.mkdir();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(testDirectory+"/file.csv");
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            long total = 0;
            int progress = 0;
            while ((count=is.read(data)) != -1){
                total += count;
                int progress_temp = (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile;
                if(progress_temp%10 == 0 && progress != progress_temp){
                    progress = progress_temp;
                }
                fos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
```

How can I add to this code to make it download all the files from that folder?

Comment: Hey I need help with downloading files using as3 on to my android. You said this script works? Can you help me get it working cause it's not working for me?

Comment: I just need a single file download

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a script at server's end, which first gives you list of all the files inside a folder, and then your application downloads each file one by one.

Comment: hmmm is that the only way? if so do you know where i could go to find such script? also the folder is going to have different types of images with unique image names, would the script be able to keep the names of the images

Comment: Is there not a way to just say go download the entire folder and copy it to SD card

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you just said. although, the script will be dynamic enough to give u the latest list

Comment: Any links to this script or idea what it would look like?

Comment: What if i point to a ZIP file on the server with all the images? then i could download that file and unzip the images

Comment: That's also quite feasible. Provided that you are able to extract the ZIP on the device's end

Answer (score 4):

```
public class DownloadFileService extends Service implements ConfigCommonVars {

private static final int NOTIFICATION = 0;
private NotificationManager mNM;
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

ArrayList<String> mServerFileListApp = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> mDeviceFileListApp = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
    showNotification();
    Toast.makeText(this, " device Services ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.

    File directory = new File(SDCardRoot+DOC_FOLDER_NAME);

    // create directory if not exists 
    if(!directory.exists())
    {
        if(directory.mkdirs()) //directory is created;
            Log.i(" download ","App dir created");
        else 
            Log.w(" download ","Unable to create app dir!");
    }

    mDeviceFileListApp = getDeviceFiles();
    Toast.makeText(this, " device file  "+mDeviceFileListApp.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                try {
                    mServerFileListApp = getServerFiles();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }).start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Cancel the persistent notification.
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);

    // Tell the user we stopped.
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.local_service_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void showNotification() {

    /*// In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.local_service_started);

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, text,System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, this.Controller.class), 0);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.local_service_label),text, contentIntent);

    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
    */

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<String> getDeviceFiles()
{
    mDeviceFileListApp = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = new File(SDCardRoot+DOC_FOLDER_NAME);
    if(directory.length()!=0) // check no of files 
    {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isFile())
                mDeviceFileListApp.add(file.getName());        
        }
    }
    return mDeviceFileListApp;
}

public ArrayList<String>  getServerFiles()
{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    JSONArray mFileArray = null;
    String mfileNames ;
    mServerFileListApp = new ArrayList<String>();


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(HTTP+SITE_URL+WEB_SERVICES_PATH+"bmservicecontroller.php?PAGE=loginpage&OPTION=downloadFile&TYPE=1");

    // get list of file in download folder 
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        char[] buf = new char[1000];
        int l = 0;
        while (l >= 0)
        {
            builder.append(buf, 0, l);
            l = reader.read(buf);
        }
        inputStream.close();

        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener( builder.toString());
        JSONObject finalResult = new JSONObject( tokener );

        mFileArray = finalResult.getJSONObject("FSSEAPI").getJSONArray("FileName");

        for (int i = 0; i < mFileArray.length(); i++)
        {
            try {
                mfileNames = mFileArray.getString(i);
                mServerFileListApp.add(mfileNames);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //showError("File Not Found " + mfileNames);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } // for ends

        String temp;
        for (int i=0; i<mServerFileListApp.size(); i++)
        {
            temp = mServerFileListApp.get(i);
            if(! mDeviceFileListApp.contains(temp))
            {
                Log.i(" File Download Start ",HTTP+SITE_URL+DOWNLOAD_PATH+temp);
                downloadFileManager(HTTP+SITE_URL+DOWNLOAD_PATH,temp);                  
            }
            else
            {
                // check and Delete File Exists
                Log.i(" File Deleted  ",HTTP+SITE_URL+DOWNLOAD_PATH+temp);
                /*
                File checkFile = new File(SDCardRoot+DOC_FOLDER_NAME+temp);

                if(checkFile.exists())
                    if(checkFile.delete())
                        Log.i(" File Deleted  ",HTTP+SITE_URL+DOWNLOAD_PATH+temp);
                    else 
                        Log.i(" File Not Delete ",HTTP+SITE_URL+DOWNLOAD_PATH+temp);
                */
            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showError("File Download Error ");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //showError("File Download Error ");
    }

    return mServerFileListApp;  
}

public void downloadFileManager(String path,String file)
{
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(path+file));
    request.setDescription(file+"descrition");
    request.setTitle(file+"title");
    // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        //request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DOC_FOLDER_NAME, file);

    // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
}
```